# AWS S3 SDK - Copy Versioned Object into same bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RestoringPreviousVersions.html) method mentioned by AWS, I am trying to create an API that would allow me to rollback to previous versions with a Lambda Function that will be hooked up to API Gateway. I will need the object, specified by version id, to overwrite the existing object in the same bucket.

```
const copyObjectAsync = params => s3.copyObject(params).promise();
const copyObjectParams = obj => ({
  Bucket: s3bucket,
  CopySource: `/${s3bucket}/${obj.objectkey}?versionId=${
    obj.versionId
  }`,
  Key: obj.objectkey,
  Tagging: `commit=${obj.commit}`,
});

const revert = async req => {
  const result = await Promise.all(
    req.payload.map(obj => {
      const params = copyObjectParams(obj);
      return copyObjectAsync(params);
    })
  );

  return result;
};
```

However, I am not having any luck. I get the following response:

```
{
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "code": "AccessDenied",
    "region": null,
    "time": "2019-04-19T17:59:59.971Z",
    "statusCode": 403,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 80.54565963302768
}
```

If I instead do a get object at a specific version and store that object in memory and then pass it through in `putObject`, it works fine.

Here are how my policies are setup:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: is there an analogous permission for "GetObjectVersion" that is "PutObjectVersion"?

Comment: @Catalyst based on what I can see from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html there isn't a specific `PutObjectVersion`.

Comment: Does the object in question have an ACL?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may lack of `s3:PutObjectAcl` as it is being set to private by default.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html states

> When copying an object, you can preserve most of the metadata (default) or specify new metadata. However, the ACL is not preserved and is set to private for the user making the request.